# How to scrape data from istio-envoy containers

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, istio

I am trying to scrape data from Istio envoy at 15090 port using prometheus.

My current setup is with istio 1.1.5 with standalone prometheus(not the one which comes attached with istio)

Envoy sidecars are attached to multiple pods in different namespaces and I am not sure how to scrape data on specific port in multiple istio-proxy containers

I tried using service monitor to scrape data from istio envoy and its not working.

Service monitor which I tried currently.

````
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  annotations:
  labels:
    k8s-app: istio
  name: envoy
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  endpoints:
  - interval: 5s
    path: /metrics
    port: http-envoy-prom
  jobLabel: envoy
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
    - istio-system
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      istio: mixer```

can somebody help, how to scrape data from port 15090 on multiple istio-proxy containers attached to multiple pods.
````

Answer (score 6):

Apart from ServiceMonitor you also need to create following  scrape config for envoy proxies

```
 # Scrape config for envoy stats
    - job_name: 'envoy-stats'
      metrics_path: /stats/prometheus
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: pod
      relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_name]
        action: keep
        regex: '.*-envoy-prom'
      - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
        action: replace
        regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
        replacement: $1:15090
        target_label: __address__
      - action: labelmap
        regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
        action: replace
        target_label: namespace
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
        action: replace
        target_label: pod_name
      metric_relabel_configs:
      # Exclude some of the envoy metrics that have massive cardinality
      # This list may need to be pruned further moving forward, as informed
      # by performance and scalability testing.
      - source_labels: [ cluster_name ]
        regex: '(outbound|inbound|prometheus_stats).*'
        action: drop
      - source_labels: [ tcp_prefix ]
        regex: '(outbound|inbound|prometheus_stats).*'
        action: drop
      - source_labels: [ listener_address ]
        regex: '(.+)'
        action: drop
      - source_labels: [ http_conn_manager_listener_prefix ]
        regex: '(.+)'
        action: drop
      - source_labels: [ http_conn_manager_prefix ]
        regex: '(.+)'
        action: drop
      - source_labels: [ __name__ ]
        regex: 'envoy_tls.*'
        action: drop
      - source_labels: [ __name__ ]
        regex: 'envoy_tcp_downstream.*'
        action: drop
      - source_labels: [ __name__ ]
        regex: 'envoy_http_(stats|admin).*'
        action: drop
      - source_labels: [ __name__ ]
        regex: 'envoy_cluster_(lb|retry|bind|internal|max|original).*'
        action: drop
```

Or use this [script](https://github.com/istio/tools/blob/master/perf/istio-install/setup_prometheus.sh)